# Date Format in Informatica

Tags: sql, informatica, informatica-powercenter, to-date

I am trying to convert a string to date in Informatica as follows

```
 TO_DATE('10/21/2014 0:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY MI:SS')
```

but it throws an error for incorrect string. 
Can Informatica process this date format: `MM/DD/YYYY MI:SS`? If not, is there any solution to process this date format in Informatica?

Comment: it works fine for me, please check your source data again. Also, are you sure it should be MI:SS instead of HH:MI? Anyway, Informatica would interpret the hour as 00.

Comment: It works with me , howevere you can check with TO_DATE(col, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS')  
otherwise the another solution is to_date(susbtsr(col,1,10),''DD/MM/YYYY')

Answer (score 1):

You need to use MI:

TO_DATE(FIELD, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS')

Comment: I guess HH24 makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

What I am  thinking is  **TO_DATE('10/21/2014 0:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY MI:SS')**. The timestamp part in the given string is invalid. It should be HH:MI(00:00)...

Answer (score 1):

Try following (I believe MOHAMMED may be implying same but without actual code snippet it isnt clear)

```
TO_DATE('10/21/2014 00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY MI:SS')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following snippet :

```
TO_DATE( 'Your_Date', 'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI:SS' )
```

You can check for more examples on the below link :
[to_date_function](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-0/transformation-language-reference/functions/to_date.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is also a difference between two digit times and single digit times. I usually detect the input and then either reject it using Error() if it doesn't fit the format or add the appropriate leading digits depending on the rules to be applied.